# How do I put a background behind my swf in flash builder using actionscript?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder

On Flash Builder, I have an ActionScript Mobile App, and an swf file (made on a different software) on it. Everything works well, but the trouble is that the swf file doesn't fill the whole screen on most devices, as it is only 480 x 320. I do not want to change the proportion anyway, as it would be unfair to players with wider screens.

So, I would like to know if there was a way to fill in this blank space with a different image.

Comment: What's so bad about my question?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have three threads concerning this issue.  If so, try being more clear and concise in a single question.  That said, if they are all the same issue, perhaps you've provided a key piece of info is in this thread: that your swf file is "made on a different software".  Did you write that swf?  Can you edit its code?  If you're trying to plunk down an external swf into your app, it may be trying to fill the screen, and padding the sides with its own settings (white background).